# How do I check what elements in a list are divisible by five in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have two functions in my program.  The one that is commented out mods every element in a list by five.  And the second function counts how many times an element appears in a list.  How do I combine both of these to get my desired result of determining how many elements of a list are divisible by five?

Here is my code:

```lisp
(defun divide-bye-five (lst)
  (loop for x in lst collect (mod x 5)))

(defun counter (a lst)
  (cond ((null lst) 0)
        ((equal a (car lst)) (+ 1 (counter a (cdr lst))))
        (t (counter a (cdr lst)))))

(counter '0 '(0 0 0 20 0 0 0 0 0 5 31))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need just select all elemets in list, which are dividable by five, you can use `remove-if-not`.

```
(defun dividable-by-5 (num)
  (zerop (mod num 5))

CL-USER> (remove-if-not #'dividable-by-5 '(1 2 3 10 15 30 31 40)) 
(10 15 30 40)
```

But I'm not sure, do you want select this elements, or just count them? Of course you can count them by calling `length` on resulting list, or of you don't need all elements, but just a number, you can use [`count-if`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_countc.htm#count-if).

```
CL-USER> (count-if #'dividable-by-5 '(1 2 3 10 15 30 31 40)) 
4
```

Comment: Is count-if a predicate function? I apologize but I'm new to LISP and it all seems pretty confusing to me.

Comment: What does `zerop` do in this case?

Comment: @ArtforLife checks equality to zero.

Comment: A predicate function is a function that tells you if a condition is true or not. They usually end in `p` (for "predicate"), like `zerop`, and are often passed to functions like `count-if` or `remove-if-not` using the `#'function-name` syntax to specify what condition to filter on. This answer instead defines a custom predicate function _using_ `zerop` to test divisibility by 5, and passes _that_ to `remove-if-not` or `count-if`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two functions where the result of one is what you would like as the input for the second you can combine them like this:

```lisp
(second-fun (first-fun first-fun-arg ...))
```

So specifically using your provided functions it should work doing:

```lisp
(counter 0 (divide-bye-five '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))) ; ==> 2
```

If you'd like to abstract it you make it a function:

```lisp
(defun count-dividable-with-five (lst)
  (counter 0 (divide-bye-five lst)))
```